# nod-gyp include dirs not working

Tags: c++, node.js, node-gyp

I met some problem while using `node-gyp` to build my C++ code. I would like to include some directories that contain *.h file in sub-directory, but it always shows error `No such file or directory`. Does anyone who have experience with `node-gyp` can give me some advice.

Here is my directory structure

```
----libraries
   ----library
       ----modules.h  // define a_module.h in modules.h
       ----a_module.h 
       ----a_module.cpp
   ----src
       ----main.h
----binding.gyp
----addon.cc
```

and my `binding.gyp` file is below:

```
{
  "targets": [
    {
      "target_name": "addon",
      "sources": [ 
        "addon.cc", 
        "./libraries/src/main.cpp"
      ],
      "include_dirs": [
      ],
      "dependencies": [
        "libs"
      ]
    },
    {
      "target_name": "libs",
      "type": "<(library)",
      "include_dirs": [
        "./libraries/libraru/",
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

I also try the config below:

```
{
  "targets": [
    {
      "target_name": "addon",
      "sources": [ 
        "addon.cc", 
        "./libraries/src/main.cpp"
      ],
      "include_dirs": [
        "./libraries/library/"
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

I try to call my program with the following path: `main.cc` -> `main.h` -> `modules.h` -> `a_module.h` -> `a_module.cpp`.

codes in `main.cc`

```
#include "./libraries/src/main.h"
```

codes in `main.h`

```
#include "library/modules.h" // <- No such file or directory error occurred
```

Is there anything wrong in my `binding.gyp` file?

Thanks for viewing my question.